# fill parent in HorizontalScrollView

Tags: android, android-layout

I use this code for scroll view and i select fill-parent for both width and height. but only height are fill parent and not width.
i want that each button fill the whole screen.

[image]

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<HorizontalScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:fillViewport="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:text="Button1" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:text="Button2" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:text="Button3" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:text="Button4" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:text="Button5" />

    </LinearLayout>
</HorizontalScrollView>
```

Comment: do you mean every button should appear over the complete screen and you want to switch between these buttons by a swipe gesture? Or do you just want to fill the width and not the height? In the first case you need ViewPager, in the second case, you have to change the orientation of your second linearLayout to `vertical` and `layout_width="fill_parent"`

Comment: yes i mean every button should appear over the complete screen and you want to switch between these buttons by a swipe gesture. one of buttons in screen each time

Comment: for horizontal scrollview item will always horizontally raped and same for Scrollview item will be vertically rapped ... so you can user `viewpager`

Comment: so it is not possible for horizontalScrollView?